# ChatHub.OnDisconnected() no suitable method found to override error in chat application

Tags: asp.net, signalr, jscript, overriding

I am building a chat application and this is the error I am getting

```
ChatHub.OnDisconnected()': no suitable method found to override
```

My code is

```
 .......

  public override System.Threading.Tasks.Task OnDisconnected()
    {
        var item = ConnectedUsers.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId);
        if (item != null)
        {
            ConnectedUsers.Remove(item);

            var id = Context.ConnectionId;
            Clients.All.onUserDisconnected(id, item.UserName);

        }

        return base.OnDisconnected();
    }....
```

I have index.html where the signalR is referenced

```
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="Css/ChatStyle.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Css/JQueryUI/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css">





<!--Script references. -->
<!--Reference the jQuery library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/ui/jquery.ui.resizable.js"></script>



<!--Reference the SignalR library. -->
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>

<!--Reference the autogenerated SignalR hub script. -->
<script src="/signalr/hubs"></script>
```

I have added 2.1.2.min.js also and I have installed latest version in SignalR .I dont know how to resolve it .Please help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to alter the method now since the new version takes a `bool`..

`ChatHub.OnDisconnected()` now becomes `ChatHub.OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)`, and you do the same in the call to the `base`....

`return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);`

Take a look at the [*Breaking Changes*](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/releases/tag/2.1.0) in the link.

For the other issue, check the information and version in your config against the dll version you're referencing...

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" 
                                                                 culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Comment: The error resolved but when I run the app I am getting this error   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Comment: The ChatHub.OnDisconnected() error arose again suddenly. I don't know wats going on @christiandev

Answer (score 2):

You have to use this function in SignalR 2

```
 public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
            {
                // Add your own code here.
                // For example: in a chat application, mark the user as offline, 
                // delete the association between the current connection id and user name.
                return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
            }
```